# Python Selenium inner for loop doesn't iterate

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Below is my code that I use for scraping the BSE web-site. All works fine, except for a minor glitch. The inner (second) for-loop doesn't iterate and  the execution ends.
Any help would be useful.

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.bseindia.com/markets/keystatics/Keystat_index.aspx')
for i in range(1,48):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddltype']/option["+str(i)+"]").click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit"]').click()
    data = []
    for j in range(2,21):
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvReport_ctl"+str(j).zfill(2)+"_Linkbtn']").click()
        for tr in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvYearwise"]'):
            ths = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
            tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
            if ths: 
                data.append([th.text for th in ths])
            if tds: 
                data.append([td.text for td in tds])
            f.write(str(data) + "\n")
```

Comment: Maybe `browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvYearwise"]')` returns an empty list?

Comment: @suit no, im getting the first iterated list as result.

Comment: is `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvReport` the table that you wanna scrape?

Comment: @skrubber: yes, that is the table

Comment: Then maybe first list is the last?

Comment: the code is correct. The problem is with website. The website throws 500 error on those click. This page isn’t working
www.bseindia.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @suit no. its just the first list. the webpage is javascript rendered. so u have to click the link (mentioned in the second for-loop) then copy table contents - which for me works once, but doesn't iterate

Comment: @imox thanks for ur effort, but i dont think that is d case. d website works perfectly well.

Comment: @Ted no way, I just tested it both with selenium and just the browser too. Are you sure?

Comment: You mean AJAX? If your elements are being loaded one by one, then `browser.find_elements_by_xpath(..)` find the first and returns it, because others just not loaded yet. Try iter a generator object, which will be making `find_elements_by_xpath(..)` each time you call next element

Comment: @suit yes, the table (which i intend to scrape) opens only after clicking the text-button. but, my problem is that the for loop doesn't move to the click function itself (for the second time).

Comment: @imox it happens sometimes, u try clicking on the year a couple of times and u should get the monthwise list loaded below thro javascript.

Comment: @Ted what do you want as output? your second loop is working fine and iterate 1 time. which i think is correct because ids are unique in html? tell me what you want and I can try helping you :-)

Comment: @imox the second loop iterates and gives me result. but the first for-loop : which is clicking the years (2017-18, 2016-17, 2015-16 etc) doesn't loop. it owuld be very helpful if you can help out.. thanks man.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many times click leads to 500 so i ran recursive try catch block.

Here is the whole code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

base_url="http://www.bseindia.com/markets/keystatics/Keystat_index.aspx"
#browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/qriyoinfolabs/ahlat/chromedriver')
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(base_url)
data = []


def fetch_this_erroful_page_for_me(id):
    try:
        print "Trying "+str(id)+"..."
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddltype']/option["+str(id)+"]").click()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit"]').click()
    except:
        print "Retrying "+str(id)+"..."
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.get(base_url)
        fetch_this_erroful_page_for_me(id)

def click_on_this_link_for_me(year_id,option_id):
    try:
        print "Trying year"+str(year_id)+"..."
        zfilled_id=str(year_id).zfill(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvReport_ctl"+zfilled_id+"_Linkbtn']").click()
        return 1
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return 0
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
        fetch_this_erroful_page_for_me(option_id)
        click_on_this_link_for_me(year_id,option_id)

for i in range(1,48):
    fetch_this_erroful_page_for_me(i)

    for j in range(2,21):

        valid=click_on_this_link_for_me(j,i)
        if(valid==0):
            print "valid0"
            break
        for tr in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvYearwise"]'):
            ths = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
            tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
            if ths:
                data.append([th.text for th in ths])
            if tds: 
                data.append([td.text for td in tds])


with open('str.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(str(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

`'//[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvYearwise"]'` is not a `tr` tag, this is a `table`. So `browser.find_elements_by_xpath(..)` returns just one element.
Try `'//[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvYearwise"]//tr'`

Btw, this is realy bad practice to do like `for i in range(1,48)`. Try to make some iterable objects with elements or element generator.

For example (I am no shure that works well, because didn't test it properly - there is `HTTP ERROR 500` issue):

```
def get_next_row(driver, xpath):
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            yield driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[i]
        except IndexError:
            break
        i += 1

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(0.5)
browser.get('http://www.bseindia.com/markets/keystatics/Keystat_index.aspx')

for list_item in get_next_row(browser, "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddltype']/option"):
    list_item.click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit"]').click()
    data = []
    for next_button in get_next_row(browser, '//a[contains(@id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvReport_ct")]'):
        next_button.click()
        for tr in get_next_row(browser, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvYearwise"]//tr'):
            ths = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
            tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
            if ths:
                data.append([th.text for th in ths])
            if tds:
                data.append([td.text for td in tds])
            f.write(str(data) + "\n")
```